# C/C++: is there a way to create a nonzero-length file atomically?

Tags: c++, c, file, filesystems

I have a thread which watches a directory for file additions (using `inotify` if it exists, polling otherwise), and notifies a listener upon new files created in the watched directory. The listener has conditional logic based on the size of the created file, which it determines using `int stat(const char *pathname, struct stat *statbuf)`.

In a separate thread, I create a nonzero-length file using std::ofstream; a simplified example of the file creation is:

```
std::ofstream ofs( "/path/to/file", std::ofstream::out );
ofs << "abc";
ofs.close()
```

Runtime behavior is that the listener, invoking `stat()`, sometimes sees the file as 0-length.

This is perfectly reasonable, since the file creation and content-addition are separate actions.

**Question: Is there a way to atomically create a nonzero-length file using either `C` functions or `C++03`'s `stl`?**

Note: For the purpose of this question, I'm not interested in synchronization primitives, like mutexes or semaphores, to synchronize the two threads around the entire process of file-open, add content, close-file.

Comment: Why not just copy a existing file into the directory?

Comment: You might be able to create the file in a _different_ directory.  After you close the file you can move (rename) the file to the correct directory.  Would `inotify` detect the file then?

Comment: @NathanOliver - I wondered about that: whether a copy of a nonzero file would work as an "atomic" appearance of a nonzero file, or if copy itself goes through a non-atomic process of (1) 0-length file creation, (2) content-addition, (3) file closing.

Comment: It is my understanding that the only non-trivial POSIX operation that is at least somewhat atomic in at least a somewhat portable fashion is a `rename` that does not cross a filesystem / device boundary. But my POSIX-fu is very weak.

Comment: I would suggest when you create the new file in the separate thread (ex. test.txt) name it something like text.txt.part then in your first thread have it ignore files with .part extension.  Then when you're ready, rename the file to it's correct name.  This might actually help you in the long run since other processes commonly use .part to signal an incomplete file (such as when you're downloading a file, or someone is uploading a file too you).  However I'm not sure if renaming it will register as a new file.

Comment: Short answer: Under Unix-like systems, at least, no, there is no standard create-file-with-contents operation.  `open()` is nice and atomic, and `write()` is nice and atomic, but obviously the sequence of the two is not.  (But as others have suggested, `rename` is nice and atomic, and therefore might be a nice solution to your problem.)

Comment: @NathanOliver The copying program would necessarily be doing the same `open` followed by `write` and so wouldn't be any more atomic.

Comment: Depending on the filesystem you use, a rename is most likely atomic (if you stay within the same filesystem). So, write a new file, then rename (move) it into place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The base C language has no such concepts, and I don't think C++ does either. If you're talking about these type of things, you must be assuming POSIX or some other operating-system-level behavior specification.

Under POSIX, the way to do this kind of operation is to create the file with a temporary name, then `rename` it only after you finish writing it. You can do that in a different directory if they're both on the same device; if they're on different devices, whether that works is implementation-defined. The most portable way is to do it in the same directory, which means that your `inotify` (Linux-specific, BTW) listener should ignore files not matching the naming pattern it's looking for or ignore files in a particular temp namespace you choose as your convention.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to atomically create a nonzero-length file using either C functions or C++03's stl?

Best approach would be to create the file elsewhere on the same filesystem, and then `std::rename` the file into the target file.

The standard doesn't really give explicit guarantees except for the post-coditions (either the file exists with new name, or the old name). Nothing about observable intermediate states. In practice, you're at the mercy of the file system. But if there is some standard operation that achieves what you want, then this is it. POSIX standard does require `rename` to be atomic.

Comment: Note that if you are monitoring the whole directory, you would need to either ignore the initial name (or family of names) or create it elsewhere on the same device. I don't think the stl rename spec guarantees to support renaming as move, though the underlying OS call probably does and it doesn't do any checking, so the filter on your directory monitor is the most robust solution..